# Can I use opamp to convert 5V DC into 10V DC?

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc-dc-converter, boost

Can I use an opamp as given below to convert 5V to 10V DC?
[image]

If yes then why do we go for BOOST converters?
[image]

If both methods are suitable then which is better method and why?

Comment: Yes, an opamp can easily amplify a 5V *signal* to 10V, but it requires an external power supply >10V in order to accomplish that. A boost converter is used to convert *power* at 5V to 10V when there is no other higher voltage supply available. Completely different applications.

Comment: Yes you can - if you feed the opamp with 12V or at least some supply voltage higher than 10V. The opamp is a voltage control device, not a voltage generator - it can output any voltage between its supply rails. Some have trouble outputting voltages close to a supply rail, which is why I suggested a 12V supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that would seem to work. As drawn your op-amp has a gain of 2, so with an input voltage of 5V, the output is 10V. 10V is within the supply voltage of -15V to +15V, so no problem there.

However there is a bit of confusing terminology in your question: most people would not talk of this op-amp "converting" a voltage in this way. Usually "converting X volts to Y volts" means specifically converting one voltage source intended to be used as a power supply to another voltage source. An op-amp might work for that purpose, but more common would be to go for a linear regulator like LM7812 or LM317. These are able to provide a more stable output voltage, come in packages able to dissipate more heat, and often have thermal overload protection and other such nice features.

To your other question: why use boost converters? In a linear regulator, input current equals output current, but input voltage is higher than output voltage. Considering that power is the product of voltage and current, it's also the case for a linear regulator than input power is greater than output power. This excess power is converted to heat, which means it gets hot, and isn't very efficient for a battery powered device, say. If you require a large amount of current the heat may be excessive.

Boost converters on the other hand are not linear circuits, and can in theory convert voltages with 100% efficiency. In practice, with real components, efficiency around 70% to 90% is achievable.

Comment: In the circuit which I have drawn 5V is my input voltage and the supply voltage i.e VCC= 15 V. So I understand that output voltage can never be greater than  15V, but what is the problem in achieving 10 V? 
Please make me understand if I am messing up with my concepts.

Comment: @NikhilPandya Ah sorry, that wasn't clear from the schematic. Could you perhaps redraw it with the built-in schematic editor (edit your question, and look for it in the toolbar) and include the power supply?

Comment: I have edited it. Please consider the new diagram.

Comment: As Phil says, an op-amp can amplify a signal from 5 volts to 10 volts, provided a higher voltage power supply is available, but cannot deliver much current at that voltage.  A boost converter is a power supply that will operate from a 5 volt supply, and produce 10 volts at a significant current, without the aid of an existing higher supply voltage.

Comment: Consider the *current* - very little current will be taken from the 5V, and all of the current output on the 10V will be taken from the 15V supply.

Answer (score 9):

*Think* about it.  Where does the opamp get 10 V from?  It comes from its supply voltage.  Opamps don't magically make more voltage.  They can only vary their output to voltages between the supply voltages they are given.

What a boost converter can do that a opamp can't, is to actually make a higher voltage than anything it is given.  If you only have 5 V, then a opamp can't give you 10 V, but a boost converter can.

Comment: Cant opamp use its supply voltage i.e 15 Volts to amplify 5V to 10V?

Comment: If you have a 15 V supply, why not get your 10 V from that?

Comment: @NikhilPandya That's what the answer you got. Whatever extra voltage needed for the stepping up the voltage comes from the supply voltage you are providing

Comment: You speak about voltage, but what about current? Using an opamp in this way will only give you a few milliamps. A boost converter can supply amperes of current.